# Im using gateway automatic locator. How can i exclude my auth-microservice from filters?

Tags: jwt, microservices, bearer-token, spring-cloud-gateway, service-discovery

I'm using automatic locator for my gateway. But i want to exclude AuthenticationFilter for some microservices.

[image]

I must exclude some microservices from filter. So i can access them without authentication.